# How do I stop a Linux computer from sending a DHCP hostname?

Tags: linux, dhcp, hostname, isc-dhcp

I need to set up a Linux computer so that it uses DHCP but doesn't send any hostname at all.

- I'm using `isc-dhclient-4.2.4`
- `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` contains the line `send host-name = gethostname();`

I've tried commenting out that line and restarting. I've also tried changing it to `send host-name = ;` and restarting. In both cases, Wireshark shows that it's still sending its hostname in a DHCP request.

How do I get it to stop sending a hostname?

Comment: Why would you go out of your way not to send a hostname?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the *hostname* and not the *FQDN* (fully-qualified domain name)? Can we see the wireshark output? Are you 100% sure it's a hostname that appears in it and not a FQDN?